# Wordpress PHP issue in functions.php regarding if and else if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

My Home page is a static custom Login Page for a network multisite with the Theme-my-login plugin running om a Divi child theme.
On the login page there is the login itself which works fine, and below that two "action links" for "Register" and "Lost Password".
I have two custom pages to link to for both links.

So I edit the child theme's functions.php file.
Let’s say you wanted to change the default Register action link to a different URL:

```
function tml_action_url( $url, $action, $instance ) {
    if ( 'register' == $action )
        $url = 'YOUR REGISTRATION URL HERE';
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'tml_action_url', 'tml_action_url', 10, 3 );
```

That works perfectly. If I want to include the lost password link too however:

```
function tml_action_url( $url, $action, $instance ) {
    if ( 'register' == $action )
        $url = 'YOUR REGISTRATION URL HERE';
    else if ( 'lost password' == $action )
        $url = 'YOUR LOST PASSWORD URL HERE';
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'tml_action_url', 'tml_action_url', 10, 3 );
```

it breaks for some reason.
Any help much appreciated. I have a feeling I'm not using the correct syntax or something.
TIA.
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation

> Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Either use `elseif` instead of `else if` or use curly brackets like so:

```
function tml_action_url( $url, $action, $instance ) 
{
    if ( 'register' == $action )
    {
        $url = 'YOUR REGISTRATION URL HERE';
    }
    else if ( 'lost password' == $action )
    {
        $url = 'YOUR LOST PASSWORD URL HERE';'
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Heaps! I can finally sleep now I know what was causing that :D

Comment: Thanks again Igor, here's how the final code turned out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908534/change-register-lost-password-action-links-urls-titles-modify-error-pages